# Wicked-PDF image render with Rails Active Storage

Tags: wicked-pdf, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I cannot get wicked_pdf to display an image from active storage to a pdf file. 
Do I use: `wicked_pdf_image_tag` or  `wicked_pdf_asset_base64` or just `image_tag` in the pdf template. Then do I give a `rails_blob_path(company.logo)` or just `company.logo` to any other method?

Answer (score 6):

There is some ongoing work to add Active Storage support to `wicked_pdf` in [this GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/716)

Until that is added (you can help!), you can create a helper method something like this (which is a slightly modified version of an example from the thread above):

```
# Use like `image_tag(wicked_active_storage_asset(user.avatar))`
def wicked_active_storage_asset(asset)
  return unless asset.respond_to?(:blob)
  save_path = Rails.root.join('tmp', asset.id.to_s)
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << asset.blob.download
  end
  save_path.to_s
end
```

Or, if you can use web resources directly in your PDF creation process:

```
<img src="<%= @user.avatar.service_url %>">
<img src="<%= @user.avatar.variant(resize: "590").processed.service_url %>">
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of
<%= image_tag url_for(@student_course.try(:avatar)) %>
i used
<%= image_tag polymorphic_url(@student_course.try(:avatar)) %>

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use `service_url` like this

```
image_tag(company.logo.service_url)
```

More info here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-service_url

Comment: This worked great. Previously the active storage URL (redirect) would cause wickedPDF to hang, and lock up the rails app.

Answer (score 0):

Unixmonkey's suggested solution worked, but I don't like that the asset is downloaded every time, even if it already exists in the `tmp` directory.

This is the modified version that worked best for me. I've based the path on the blob key, which should ensure the latest version of our asset is rendered. `Pathname` is required to ensure that the directories are created for the path:

```rb
    # Use like `image_tag(wicked_active_storage_asset(facility.logo))`
    def wicked_active_storage_asset(asset)
      return unless asset.respond_to?(:blob)
      save_path = Rails.root.join('tmp', asset.blob.key)
      begin
        require 'pathname'
        some_path = Pathname(save_path)
        some_path.dirname.mkpath
        File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
          file << asset.blob.download
        end
      end unless File.exist?(save_path)
      save_path
    end
```